# Where to store ansible repo used/updateable by some users, readable by others

Tags: filesystems

We have an ubuntu 22 ansible server.
On this server we want to run ansible playbooks, multiple users will run the ansible playbooks, but we want to have them run it under their own name, so without a dedicated ansible user.
We can make a group ansible_users for that purpose.

The ansible playbooks are stored in git, multiple users can make changes, so we want the users on the ansible server to be uble to git pull the updates.

In which location should the repo be stored?

I was thinking maybe `/opt` or `/usr/local/src` or `/usr/src` but im really not sure what makes sense. What would be a good location for a git repo, that should be updateable/useable by multiple users.

Context:
Lets say we have two people working on the code in the git repo, they are both allowed to update the server code with the changes in the git repo (git pull).

But there are other people who are allowed to read/use the ansible playbooks, but are not allowed to git pull/change the code.

The goal is to have one source of truth, so not have all the users checkout the repo themselves in their home directory.

But if I put it in /tmp the repo will be removed, it is also not owned by one person, so putting it in someone's home dir also does not make sense.

What directory would make sense?

Comment: Do you mean updated by users who are local on a single host? And all making changes to a single directory?

Comment: @AlexD we have multiple users on the server, and also multiple users in git, if someone makes a change in git, the users on the ansible server (with access) should be able to do a git pull to get the latest version.

Comment: Do you expect two users to do 'git pull' in the same directory at the same time?

Comment: @AlexD lets say we have two people who work with the ansible files, one on monday and the other on tuesday, the goal is that they both are able to add updates in git, and than pull the changes on the server. They should use the same directory so they do not both need to pull the updates. There are also other people who will be allowed to use the files but not update them.

Comment: `/usr` and everything underneath is supposed for more static data which can be mounted read-only. `/opt` is for software packages. I would go with `/srv/something`.

Comment: This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my suggestion follows the FHS recommendation.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Do you have a suggestion to what I can add to make it less opinion based?

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart, concentrate your question on best practice. Not on good place, best place.and as it is `git` repo everyone should keep copy in his/her home directory. Where exactly the repo is located is not important at all.

Comment: @RomeoNinov We want to have the content of the repos shared to all users. so only 2 users can git pull the repo, but all users shoul be able to read the conent. I added some context to the question

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart, this you want is managed by git repo, not directories, location, etc.

Comment: @RomeoNinov But if I put it in /tmp the repo will be removed, it is also not owned by one person, so putting it in someones home dir also does not make sense. I think the git part will be fine, but have no clue in which directory I should put it.

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart, you do not get it at all. You have **git server** which can be **EVERYWHERE**, even on other machine, even on other continent. Clients can put **local** copies (they get from server) everywhere, but usually they add it in their home directories.

Comment: @RomeoNinov that is correct, but it is also possible to make a directory read only on linux, which is what we want for some users. I added context to the question, maybe now it is understandable. we do not want multiple copies by multiple users, we want one cloned repo that is used by multiple users. For the question the whole git part does not matter, we already  handle similair cases on different servers, but the location where it should be is the discussion.

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart, I do not see ANY reason to make users use one directory instead of own copies. The second (own copies) will ensure authentication is in place and any commit will be bind to the user name and git admin can decide to approve or not (based on names)

Comment: @RomeoNinov commits are bound to a user name even in a shared directory because each user makes commits with his own UID and his own git-config. You are confusing a shared directory with a shared user account.

Comment: @AlexD, right, but all the users will share one copy instead of having own and make own changes.

Answer (score 0):

As git is a distributed version control, you are not limited to only having one copy for development and operations.

For example, [Fedora infra uses git](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/infra/sysadmin_guide/ansible/)  and is public about how it works, but of course they work off of private copies. Not to endorse anything specific that they are doing, but its clear that the list of applications and servers reflects doing real work.

People touching servers should be minimized as much as possible, to reduce the chance of unrecorded or unauthorized changes. Access to the management host running the automation ideally is much more restrictive than most things, it has the admin access to change stuff! In addition to not making changes to the automation files, people should not have access to privileged credentials, perhaps loaded into a ssh-agent.

So how to collaborate with a team?  A reference repo can be separate from the copy used for operations. For this  source of truth, make use of any git hosting you already have. Implement features like issue tracking, merge requests, role based access control, automated testing. Depending on desired workflows, people could clone personal copies from this, then propose merge requests back in to a main branch.  This is the public record of what automation exists. Fedora infra uses public repos on pagure.io for this, substitute something like a private GitLab if preferred. The output of all this is the tree that is the source of truth for approved automation.

Operations then gets a copy of this tree. On a separate management host, for security and resiliency reasons. git can fetch remote repos of course. Under this model, commits should not be done to the ops copy, but rather upstream in the dev copy, and mirrored with scripts. Not the worst thing if the ops copy needs to have commits done to it because the reference copy is down, but that will need to be resolved at some point. Fedora infra has several copies between the bare repo for the fetch, and some others. Adjust to fit how you use git.

And finally your question about what the working copy should be. My design uses git hosting features for access control upstream. There is not much need for people to write to the ops copy, so write might be limited to the service user mirroring it and a limited group of admins who know git well. Allowing multiple people to edit one working copy can cause problems, git will not prevent conflicts altering the same file at the same time.

As to where to put the tree, doesn't really matter if individual admins or the automation system can use a personal copy in their home directory or whatever.   But let's standardize anyway: it is data, not software, and not user specific, so I would tend to go with `/srv`. Indeed, Fedora infra has  `/srv/git/ansible` among other copies of the repo.  These playbooks could be run as a service user (scheduled task, on a trigger)  or by a person.  In the case of a person, wrapper scripts for access control or logging could be helpful, for example [rbac_playbook](https://bitbucket.org/tflink/ansible_utils)

Secrets should be stored separately. Such as a secret system, whose API key is only loaded into the management host running playbooks.

Overall, separating the development and operations concerns has benefits. Collaborative development on an "upstream" copy can make use of tools for software. Operations should work off a restricted access copy, running the automation tool is a privileged thing.

Imagine an ideal situation where a new hire is tasked with learning how to install an application server to the organization's specifications. They clone the public automation repo, point it at a personal test host, and make it happen. Later when they are allowed to supervise the production automation, it behaves the exact same way.